# can't run app.js in notification api | Socioboard | Node.JS

Tags: node.js, json

I installed all APIs in socioboard 4.0 [Socioboard API](https://github.com/socioboard/Socioboard-4.0/tree/master/socioboard-api)
everything is working great except notification API.
Installation part of the notification API is successful but
When I am trying to start Notification API it won't get started and landed with errors in the log file.

when I see logs I found this.

```
{ error:
   Error: Cannot parse config file: 'D:\wamp\www\api\notification\config\default.json': SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 1768
       at Config.util.parseFile (D:\wamp\www\api\notification\node_modules\config\lib\config.js:844:11)
       at D:\wamp\www\api\notification\node_modules\config\lib\config.js:600:28
       at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
       at D:\wamp\www\api\notification\node_modules\config\lib\config.js:596:14
       at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
       at Config.util.loadFileConfigs (D:\wamp\www\api\notification\node_modules\config\lib\config.js:595:13)
       at new Config (D:\wamp\www\api\notification\node_modules\config\lib\config.js:136:27)
       at Object.<anonymous> (D:\wamp\www\api\notification\node_modules\config\lib\config.js:1649:31)
       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10),
  level: 'error',
  message:
   'uncaughtException: Cannot parse config file: \'D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\config\\default.json\': SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 1768\nError: Cannot parse config file: \'D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\config\\default.json\': SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 1768\n    at Config.util.parseFile (D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\node_modules\\config\\lib\\config.js:844:11)\n    at D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\node_modules\\config\\lib\\config.js:600:28\n    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)\n    at D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\node_modules\\config\\lib\\config.js:596:14\n    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)\n    at Config.util.loadFileConfigs (D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\node_modules\\config\\lib\\config.js:595:13)\n    at new Config (D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\node_modules\\config\\lib\\config.js:136:27)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\node_modules\\config\\lib\\config.js:1649:31)\n    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)',
  stack:
   'Error: Cannot parse config file: \'D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\config\\default.json\': SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 1768\n    at Config.util.parseFile (D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\node_modules\\config\\lib\\config.js:844:11)\n    at D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\node_modules\\config\\lib\\config.js:600:28\n    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)\n    at D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\node_modules\\config\\lib\\config.js:596:14\n    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)\n    at Config.util.loadFileConfigs (D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\node_modules\\config\\lib\\config.js:595:13)\n    at new Config (D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\node_modules\\config\\lib\\config.js:136:27)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\node_modules\\config\\lib\\config.js:1649:31)\n    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)',
  exception: true,
  date: 'Fri Oct 18 2019 17:58:24 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)',
  process:
   { pid: 6156,
     uid: null,
     gid: null,
     cwd: 'D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification',
     execPath: 'D:\\node\\node.exe',
     version: 'v10.16.3',
     argv:
      [ 'D:\\node\\node.exe',
        'D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\app.js' ],
     memoryUsage:
      { rss: 38379520,
        heapTotal: 22265856,
        heapUsed: 12697168,
        external: 329283 } },
  os: { loadavg: [ 0, 0, 0 ], uptime: 663627 },
  trace:
   [ { column: 11,
       file:
        'D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\node_modules\\config\\lib\\config.js',
       function: 'Config.util.parseFile',
       line: 844,
       method: 'parseFile',
       native: false },
     { column: 28,
       file:
        'D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\node_modules\\config\\lib\\config.js',
       function: null,
       line: 600,
       method: null,
       native: false },
     { column: null,
       file: null,
       function: 'Array.forEach',
       line: null,
       method: 'forEach',
       native: false },
     { column: 14,
       file:
        'D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\node_modules\\config\\lib\\config.js',
       function: null,
       line: 596,
       method: null,
       native: false },
     { column: null,
       file: null,
       function: 'Array.forEach',
       line: null,
       method: 'forEach',
       native: false },
     { column: 13,
       file:
        'D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\node_modules\\config\\lib\\config.js',
       function: 'Config.util.loadFileConfigs',
       line: 595,
       method: 'loadFileConfigs',
       native: false },
     { column: 27,
       file:
        'D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\node_modules\\config\\lib\\config.js',
       function: 'new Config',
       line: 136,
       method: null,
       native: false },
     { column: 31,
       file:
        'D:\\wamp\\www\\api\\notification\\node_modules\\config\\lib\\config.js',
       function: null,
       line: 1649,
       method: null,
       native: false },
     { column: 30,
       file: 'internal/modules/cjs/loader.js',
       function: 'Module._compile',
       line: 778,
       method: '_compile',
       native: false },
     { column: 10,
       file: 'internal/modules/cjs/loader.js',
       function: 'Module._extensions..js',
       line: 789,
       method: '.js',
       native: false } ],
  timestamp: '2019-10-18T12:28:24.738Z' }
```

what should I do to run notification API successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an extra coma throwing error in notification/config/default.js

here I change this

```
"mailService": {
        "defaultMailOption": "<<Give the default mail services should take place (any one from => gmail,sendgridapi)>>",
        "sendgrid": {
            "username": "<<sendgrid username>>",
            "password": "<<sendgrid password>>",
            "frommail": "<<sendgrid frommail>>",
            "ccmail": "<<sendgrid ccmail>>",
            "apiKey": "<<sendgrid apiKey>>"
        },
        "gmailServices": {
            "email": "<<gmail email>>",
            "password": "<<password>>"
        }
    },
```

to this

```
"mailService": {
        "defaultMailOption": "<<Give the default mail services should take place (any one from => gmail,sendgridapi)>>",
        "sendgrid": {
            "username": "<<sendgrid username>>",
            "password": "<<sendgrid password>>",
            "frommail": "<<sendgrid frommail>>",
            "ccmail": "<<sendgrid ccmail>>",
            "apiKey": "<<sendgrid apiKey>>"
        },
        "gmailServices": {
            "email": "<<gmail email>>",
            "password": "<<password>>"
        }
    }
```

hope it might be helpful for others